# HTTP client having an issue with client certificate while trying to make a call on IIS server

Tags: c#, iis, .net-6.0, json-serialization

I am trying to connect to a 3rd party using a client certificate. I've been testing this locally using docker-compose with a docker runtime image for .net 6. This works fine. However, as soon As I push my code to my web server running IIS I get a bit of a weird error when trying to call the 3rd party API. If I remove the line where I add the certificate to the handler it works fine but then I can access the data (obviously ;P).

Note: the call when adding the certificate does not reach the 3rd party server at all. So it breaks before that, also the error is a JSON Serialization without me serializing anything myself before calling. This raises the question: what does IIS do differently compared to the image (is there a big difference with Kestrel vs IIS on forming such an HTTP request?)

This is my code:

```cs
X509Certificate2 cert = new(certificateSettings.PfxCertPath, certificateSettings.CertPassword);

HttpClientHandler handler = new();
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
HttpClient client = new(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new(baseEndpoint);

HttpResponseMessage result = client.GetAsync(endpoint).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The error:

> Connection ID "14843864373423768205", Request ID "80000290-0000-ce00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>
> Exception:
>
> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.IntPtr' instances are not supported. Path: $.innerexception.TargetSite.MethodHandle.Value.
>
> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.IntPtr' instances are not supported.
>
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.UnsupportedTypeConverter`1.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(WriteStack& state, NotSupportedException ex) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
> at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state) at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()

I have tried to add the certificate itself to our trusted certificates on the IIS server, this did as expected nothing.

I have tried to add a different cert, this did not work.

I have been searching this issue online for about two days, without any success.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be with the certificate handling, rather in de-/serializing something, specifically `System.Text.Json` cannot serialize or deserialize a `IntPtr`. Judging from your code snippet, it seems you're trying to deserialize the result of the HTTP call to an object containing a `IntPtr`

Comment: @MindSwipe It does not even reach the call. If I remove the ``handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);`` It works fine. So I don't understand it at all. I first thought the same thing, but as it works fine on a container envoirment but only has this issue on IIS and since I am not serializing / deserializing in a weird way

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this issue is caused when I return the exception. When my ApiController try's to serialize my innerexception.